# Correct validation error in console, but no red border around select2 Meteor AutoForm input field

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am using an AutoForm with a [meteor-autoform-select2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-select2/) input field. My Schema looks like this:

```
Data.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 30
    },
    users: {
        type: [String],
        autoform: {
            type: "select2",
            options: function () {
                return Users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}}).map(function (user) {
                    return {label: user.username, value: user._id};
                });
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

The `title`, as well as the `users` input field is required. If I submit my form with empty input, the `title` input gets a red border and an error appears. However, this does not apply to the `users` input field, even though I can see the correct error message in my console.

Why?

Comment: It appears your users field type is an array. Have you tried it with the same syntax as the title?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ? http://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue??